# Servlet Spec for Jboss 4.2.3

Tags: java, jboss

What Servlet Spec and JSP version does Jboss 4.2.3 support?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That depends on the Tomcat version it is using. As per the [specs/release notes](http://sourceforge.net/project/shownotes.php?release_id=614346) it is using [Tomcat 6.0.x](http://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html). Thus, it supports Servlet 2.5 / JSP 2.1.

Answer (score 6):

According to this http://community.jboss.org/wiki/VersionOfTomcatInJBossAS I think it can be read as only unofficial support for Servlet 2.5 and JSP 2.1.

So it's safer to assume Servlet 2.4 and JSP 2.0 in JBoss 4.2.3.