# 404 on GET request to Servlet

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets, jboss

I have been trying for 3 days now to create a Java EE project, that uses JSP, Servlet and EJB in a single project, as I need to do a course final assignment on this.

We were instructed to use JBOSS 4.2.3, and so that is what I try to use.

I set up my environment as follows:

1. http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/1372
2. Install IntelliJ Idea 13 Ultimate.
3. Download JBOSS and prepare a directory to use.
4. After those 3 days of hard work, I managed to get a sample app, created by this tutorial:
   http://wiki.jetbrains.net/intellij/Developing_and_running_a_Java_EE_Hello_World_application#The_Hello_World_Java_EE_application

Now, the application compiles, I get the index.jsp on: `http://localhost:8080/webWeb/`

However, I get a 404 error if I click it, and submit to `http://localhost:8080/webWeb/helloworld`

I dont know what else to try, I think I Googled and read pretty much everything :(
Here is a link to the Project archive, so that you could (potentially) test out my project, see if you can solve this problem somehow...

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/9sma5vh7usy2h3p/AADA64KPyLH29iGz8OamWyNna

Thanks!

---

UPDATE:
For convenience, my HelloWorldServlet.java code:

```
package myservlets;

import mybeans.HelloWorldBean;

import javax.ejb.EJB;
import java.io.IOException;

@javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet(name = "HelloWorldServlet", urlPatterns = "/helloworld")
public class HelloWorldServlet extends javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet {
    @EJB
    private HelloWorldBean helloWorldBean;
    protected void doPost(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest request,
                          javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse response)
            throws javax.servlet.ServletException, IOException {

    }
    @Override
    protected void doGet(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest request,
                         javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse response)
            throws javax.servlet.ServletException, IOException {
        String hello=helloWorldBean.sayHello();
        request.setAttribute("hello",hello);
        request.getRequestDispatcher("hello.jsp").forward(request,response);
    }
}
```

---

I feel I really must add, that this extreme difficulty of setting up Java to just work and allow me to focus on **CODING**, is the reason I prefer something like PHP, which just works for example... Am I wrong?

Comment: Do you have a servlet which URL pattern is `helloworld` and have implemented the `doGet` method?

Comment: Also, you should post the relevant code in the question. Do not provide your code through external links.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza: I updated the question with the Servlet, thanks! I just thought I should provide the entire package including its deploy configuration, as I feel its NOT code related.. as the code compiles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're using JBoss 4.2.3 which works with Servlet 2.5 / JSP 2.1 (as noted by BalusC here: [Servlet Spec for Jboss 4.2.3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2363711/1065197)). Usage of `@WebServlet` and annotations is supported since Servlet 3.0. So, you have to configure your servlets directly in web.xml file.

Note that servet 2.5 doesn't support EJB injection either.

Comment: How do I adjust the code then, to work with lower Servlet versions then? And change the EJB usage to non-injection? When creating the project, I had no way to specify to use Servlet 2.5....

Comment: Refer to [StackOverflow servlets wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info)

Comment: Thank you @Luiggi, I've tried re-creating the project from scratch, but following my original tutorial (http://wiki.jetbrains.net/intellij/Developing_and_running_a_Java_EE_Hello_World_application#The_Hello_World_Java_EE_application), I cant seem to have the ability to specify a Web Application version, the only option is 3.1... I also tried using JBOSS 6 which supposedly supports Annotations, but still getting 404 error there upon deployment of the project. Should I attach server log of deployment?

Comment: Do you have a web.xml for your project that explains which servlet version you're using, right? Otherwise, the application won't work.

Comment: I have tried to add the web.xml to the web Module, added the Servlet mappings, and tried to use the JBOSS 6.1.0 Final which should support newer - didnt work, lastly I tried once again the JBOSS 4.2.3 version - it works right now! I have no idea why, whats different... I have observed that even if I manually write version="2.5" in the web.xml for Servlets, IDE is not recognizing it, and it still has not worked. Something else does the trick, as right now it works, I dont know why or what... but as long as it does, thanks! :)